# How should the games "The Chronicles of Riddick: Escape from Butcher Bay" and "The Chronicles of Riddick: Assault on Dark Athena" be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

I tried to tag to tag this question: [Is the Director’s Cut the *only* PC version of “The Chronicles of Riddick: Escape from Butcher Bay”?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37763/4797), with the name of the [game it was about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Riddick:_Escape_from_Butcher_Bay) as it was initially just tagged [version-differences](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-differences).

I tried the following tags but they contain more characters than the tag length limit: [the-chronicles-of-riddick-efbb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-chronicles-of-riddick-efbb), [chronicles-of-riddick-efbb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-riddick-efbb).

I just settled with [the-chronicles-of-riddick](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-chronicles-of-riddick) (exactly 25 characters - the tag length limit).

This tag could be problematic, though, because the sequel of "*[The Chronicles of Riddick: Escape from Butcher Bay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Riddick:_Escape_from_Butcher_Bay)*" is titled "*[The Chronicles of Riddick: Assault on Dark Athena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Riddick:_Assault_on_Dark_Athena)*".

So, what is the proper way to tag questions about those two games?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Seems to me that [riddick-butcher-bay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddick-butcher-bay) and [riddick-dark-athena](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddick-dark-athena) have pretty good Google juice.

Those would probably be a safe option.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

- [tcor-escape-butcher-bay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcor-escape-butcher-bay)
- [tcor-assault-dark-athena](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcor-assault-dark-athena)

Answer (score -5):

Since all versions where at least part of the title is fully spelled out exceeds the character limit, it seems to me that the tags should just be initialisms: [cor-efbb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cor-efbb) and [cor-aoda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cor-aoda).  It's not ideal, and a good tag wiki excerpt would be necessary, but I don't see many other options.  Well, one other option: [riddick-effb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddick-effb) and [riddick-aoda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddick-aoda).